# typescript implementation of ajax async call and call back handling

Tags: typescript

In typescript I am trying to implement ajax async call and handle it through handler method. below is the code snippet:

```
var JQryAjxSetting: JQueryAjaxSettings = {
    url: "h***//test/test.svc/GetUploadId",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(error); },
    success: function () { alert("success"); },
    jsonpCallback: 'SetUpLoadID',
};
```

In above declaration I expect a `jsonpCallback:` is the place where I handle call back. in "SetUpLoadID" I want to get the response which is serialized json data. So in SetUpLoadID method how will I receive data? similar to event will I get some variable where `event.data` will give me data sent from the server as a response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In jQuery, the jsonpCallback is the name used when presenting the request to the server. The data is passed to your success function.

```
var JQryAjxSetting: JQueryAjaxSettings = {
    url: "h***//test/test.svc/GetUploadId",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    error: function (xhr, status, error) { alert(error); },
    success: function (data) { alert(data); },
    jsonpCallback: 'itDoesntMatterNotAFunction',
};
```